# How to take element from two json arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, compare

```
arr1 = [
    {Lattitude: '52,4043000', Location: 'a2', Longitude: '55,7181815'},
    {Lattitude: '52,3882320', Location: 'b2', Longitude: '55,7225500'},
    {Lattitude: '52,4041184', Location: 'c2', Longitude: '55,7172296'},
    {Lattitude: '52,3996194', Location: 'd2', Longitude: '55,7200249'},
];

arr2 = [
    {Lattitude: '52,3882320', Location: 'b2', Longitude: '55,7225500'},
    {Lattitude: '52,4041184', Location: 'c2', Longitude: '55,7172296'},
    {Lattitude: '52,3996194', Location: 'd2', Longitude: '55,7200249'}
];
```

how i can compare two json arrays arr1,arr2 an get just this element   `{Lattitude: '52,4043000', Location: 'a2', Longitude: '55,7181815'}` 
from arr1 which no in arr2

I`ll try to do like this

```
     function objDiff(arr1, arr2) {
                    var resultArray = [];


for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; arr2.length; j++) {
          if (parseFloat(parseFloat(arr1[i].Lattitude).toFixed(4)) != parseFloat(parseFloat(arr2[i].Lattitude).toFixed(4)) &&
                                parseFloat(parseFloat(arr1[i].Longitude).toFixed(4)) != parseFloat(parseFloat(arr2[i].Longitude).toFixed(4))) {
                                resultArray.push(arr1[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return resultArray;
                }
```

but my function not works, i don`t know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
        function compareArr(arr1, arr2) {
            var longArray = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
            var shortArray = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;

            return resultArr = longArray.filter(function (v) {
                return shortArray.filter(function (iv) {
                    return v.Lattitude === iv.Lattitude
                            && v.Location === iv.Location
                            && v.Longitude === iv.Longitude;
                }).length === 0;
            });
        }

        var resultArr = compareArr(arr2, arr1);
```

Pass two array to this function in any sequense, the result will be same.

Comment: This may not work if content of variables is exchanged. Not sure how OP wants it to be!

Comment: This code will execute 10 time faster than for loop.

Comment: Can you provide justification for your statement ? **10 time faster** Try this: https://jsperf.com/javascript-array-filter-versus-loop

Comment: You can compare using start time and end time. filter() or map() based iteration is 10 time faster that for loop. Try yourself.

Comment: sorry, not working, when i`m send compareArr(arr2, arr1); arr2 with json data of 50 elements, arr1 json data with 20 elements. but my 20 elements are already in 50 elements so your function not return me 0 elements that i need/