# Filter array based on another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

I have two set of array and i want filter my first array based on the second array and store the value in third array

```
$scope.SaAssingTo = [
    { "PSAID": 1, "Name": "Ajay", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 2, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 3, "Name": "anu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 4, "Name": "mohan", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 5, "Name": "java", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 6, "Name": "veenu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 7, "Name": "Ajay", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 8, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 9, "Name": "anu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 10, "Name": "mohan", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 11, "Name": "java", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
    { "PSAID": 6, "Name": "veenu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" }
];
var filter array=[2,4,6,8];
var resultarray=[
    { "PSAID": 2, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" }    
    { "PSAID": 4, "Name": "mohan", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },        
    { "PSAID": 6, "Name": "veenu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },     
    { "PSAID": 8, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
];
```

Comment: Refere to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409643/how-to-take-element-from-two-json-arrays-in-jquery/33409898?noredirect=1#comment54610797_33409898

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like so

```js
$scope = {}; // just for example

$scope.SaAssingTo = [
  { "PSAID": 1, "Name": "Ajay", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 2, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 3, "Name": "anu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 4, "Name": "mohan", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 5, "Name": "java", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 6, "Name": "veenu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 7, "Name": "Ajay", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 8, "Name": "pravin", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 9, "Name": "anu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 10, "Name": "mohan", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 11, "Name": "java", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" },
  { "PSAID": 6, "Name": "veenu", "EMail": "ajay@cgi.com" }

];

var filter = [2,4,6,8];
var result = $scope.SaAssingTo.filter(function (el) {
  return filter.indexOf(el.PSAID) >= 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to filter by `PSAID`, you could do this:

```
var resultArray = $scope.SaAssingTo.filter(function (item) {
    return filterArray.indexOf(item.PSAID) !== -1;
});
```